# Chrome's PDF reader does not always show spaces between words

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-11.04, pdf-reader

The reader does not show the spaces between words in many case. The PDF opens fine using the reader that the OS uses, so I know that I am not getting a corrupted PDF.

In addition, the reader realizes that there is a space there (I can search using the space and it will find the text) but it is just not displayed.

Here is an example:
[image: The example]

What is going on here? (using chrome 17)

Comment: Can you look into the file; might be something wrong with the PDF & not the reader. What other PDFs do you have problems with? I just opened a PDF from Intel in Chrome 18.0.1025.152m Win7_64, no issues.

Comment: @tomByer, there is no issue with the PDF itself, the one shown is the intel spec ([link](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf)).

Comment: 1) you are using a different OS and a different version of Chrome. 2) All of them. 3) See comment above for link to an example PDF, 4) As per question, it reads fine if I save it, and open it using Document Viewer 2.30.3.

Comment: Then perhaps this should be a question for Chrome's Linux bug report system, not on SuperUser?